# Not All Values Updating In DataFrame In R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to update a column in a dataframe from int to categorical.

I am running the following 4 statements just to get me started

```
goalkeepers$value_eur[goalkeepers$value_eur >= 0 & goalkeepers$value_eur <= 20000000] <- "Low"
goalkeepers$value_eur[goalkeepers$value_eur > 20000000 & goalkeepers$value_eur <= 40000000] <- "Medium - Low"
goalkeepers$value_eur[goalkeepers$value_eur > 40000000 & goalkeepers$value_eur <= 60000000] <- "Medium - High"
goalkeepers$value_eur[goalkeepers$value_eur > 60000000 & goalkeepers$value_eur <= 80000000] <- "High"
```

However, when I go back into the Dataframe, the value_eur field hasnt been updated for about 20 rows (These are normally in the "Medium - Low" value.

It is worth noting, that all expected rows are updated apart from these 20 rows. All other values that are expected to be flagged as "Medium - Low" are flagged correctly

Is this a bug in R? I really cant see how the code about will change some values in the category but not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cut` in `base R`

```
goalkeepers$value_cat <- cut(goalkeepers$value_eur, breaks = c(0, 20000000, 40000000, 60000000,80000000),
      labels = c("Low", "Medium - Low", "Medium - High", "High"))
```

---

In the OP's code, it is updating the same column in each assignment i.e. changing a `numeric` `class` to `character` and then doing the logic applied as in a `numeric` column.  Instead create a new column

```
goalkeepers$value_cat <- NA_character_
goalkeepers$value_cat[goalkeepers$value_eur >= 0 &     goalkeepers$value_eur <= 20000000] <- "Low"
goalkeepers$value_cat[goalkeepers$value_eur > 20000000 & goalkeepers$value_eur <= 40000000] <- "Medium - Low"
goalkeepers$value_cat[goalkeepers$value_eur > 40000000 & goalkeepers$value_eur <= 60000000] <- "Medium - High"
goalkeepers$value_cat[goalkeepers$value_eur > 60000000 & goalkeepers$value_eur <= 80000000] <- "High"
```

---

Or if the intention is to change the same column, then create a temporary  vector and then use that for applying the logic

```
tmpvec <- goalkeepers$value_eur
goalkeepers$value_eur[tmpvec>= 0 &  tmpvec <= 20000000] <- "Low"
goalkeepers$value_eur[tmpvec > 20000000 & tmpvec <= 40000000] <- "Medium - Low"
goalkeepers$value_eur[tmpvec > 40000000 & tmpvec <= 60000000] <- "Medium - High"
goalkeepers$value_eur[tmpvec > 60000000 & tmpvec <= 80000000] <- "High"
```